# Alternate two images in java (open and close the pacman's mouth)

Tags: java, swing, animation, 2d, pacman

I would be trying to replicate the Pacman game in Java. I made sure that through the keyboard I can make the player move and rotate it correctly by replacing the image. I can't figure out now how to make him open and close his mouth endlessly as he walks. This is my code (for now, I'm only working on the part where it walks):

The image of the pacman with his mouth closed is "playerClosed"

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class decisiva extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    
    int x=0;
    int y=0;
    int velX=0;
    int velY=0;

    Timer tm = new Timer(1,this);
    
    
    private String playerDirection="right";

    private Image playerUp = new ImageIcon("boh/imageUp.png").getImage();
    private Image playerDown = new ImageIcon("boh/imageDown.png").getImage();
    private Image playerRight = new ImageIcon("boh/imageRight.png").getImage();
    private Image playerLeft = new ImageIcon("boh/imageLeft.png").getImage();
    
    private Image playerClosed = new ImageIcon("boh/closed.png").getImage();
    
    
    public decisiva() {
        tm.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
    }
    
    
    Timer timer = new Timer(5444400,this);

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        
        if(playerDirection=="up") {
            g.drawImage(playerUp,x,y,this);
        }
        if(playerDirection=="down") {
            g.drawImage(playerDown,x,y,this);
        }
        if(playerDirection=="left") {
            g.drawImage(playerLeft,x,y,this);
        }
        if(playerDirection=="right") {
            g.drawImage(playerRight,x,y,this);
        }
        
    }
    

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        x = x+velX;
        y= y+velY;
        repaint();
    }
    
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            velX=0;
            velY=-1;
            playerDirection="up";
            
        }
        
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
            velX=1;
            velY=0;
            playerDirection="right";
        }
        
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            velX=-1;
            velY=0;
            playerDirection="left";
        }
        
        
        if(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            velX=0;
            velY=1;
            playerDirection="down";
        }
    }


    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {      
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }
}
```

and the main:

```
package player;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        decisiva t = new decisiva();
        
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        
        jf.setTitle("tutorial");
        jf.setSize(600,400);
        jf.setVisible(true);
        jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jf.add(t);

    }

}
```

[My goal is to be able to do this in the simplest way.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9h78.gif)

But for now with my code I can make it move correctly by rotating it only in the required direction.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Animating Sprite Sheets in Java using LibGdx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58958194/animating-sprite-sheets-in-java-using-libgdx)

Comment: Maybe you could use an `int` as a counter that is incremented every game tick/frame, and after it reaches a specific number you toggle the animation image and reset the counter back to zero

Comment: The simplest solution is to create four GIF files, one for each direction.

Answer (score -1):

My first question is wondering why there's only one image where the sprite's mouth is closed, as this would only allow the sprite to have it's mouth closed in one direction. However to answer your question i'd make a global int variable and use that as a timer so when it hits a certain point it will switch the image back and forth from the image with the closed mouth to the image with the open one.

```
private int openClose = 0; //the time variable that is global
```

Then in a separate function that can declare the movement of the sprite:

```
private int leftCloseIndex = 0; private Image[] leftClose = {playerLeft, playerClosed}; // list to alternate images
public void actionPerformed(){
    if (openClose != 20){
        openClose++;
    } else{
        openClose = 0;
        if (leftCloseIndex == 1){
            leftCloseIndex = 0;
        } else{
            leftCloseIndex = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: the function has to either be the actionPerformed function or referenced by it so it can update.

Comment: *"My first question is.."* Questions are for comments. Given you don't have the rep. yet to comment, take that rule as a hint that you should be patient. Focus on answering questions that do *not* need to have that opening (or text anywhere in the answer).